Merge two lists and create new list with key from one list and values from another nested list
I have two lists.
List1:
['D', 'N', 'R', 'H'] 

List2:
"d": [ 
       [ "100", "200", "300",4], 
       ["101", 201, "301",null]
     ] 

How can I merge the above two lists and create a new list from List1 as key and List2 as values?
For example:
"response": { 
              [ 
                { "D": "100","N": "200", "R": "300","H": "4"},     
                {"D": "101","N": "201","R": "301","H": null} 
              ] 
            }

I tried using a for loop, but I'm looking for any inbuilt function that merges the two lists as above.

Take a look at zip: [dict(zip(list1, x)) for x in list2]

Thanks you poke, yes i tried like this " dct = [dict(zip(keys,vals)) for vals in values]" and it worked
